# What is the purpose of using dip?

Tags: android

I'm new in Android development and I'm trying to adapt my application to every resolutions. I recently heard about the notion of dip but I don't get the purpose of this unit. I got that it permits to display something with the same physical size no matter the screen resolution.

But the thing is that it doesn't work with different screen densities. I mean that if I define an image with a width of 80dip, the result won't be the same on a 160dpi screen and a 320dpi screen. So I don't really get the purpose of this unit if I have everytime to code something to adapt a component to a device.

How can I define a layout in a xml (without code anything, it shouldn't be required :/ ) in order that this view is the same (or almost) on every device ?

I really don't get why it's not possible to use percentage in the layout (xml) rather than that kind of units.

Thank you very much for you help.

PS : Sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of a dip (also called a dp) is to have the same size virtual pixel regardless of the physical pixel density of the display.

> 1dp = 1 pixel at 160 pixels/inch (medium density display—mdpi)

At higher pixel densities, 1dp is more than one physical pixel and at lower densities, it takes more than 1dp to be the size of one physical pixel.

If you specify sizes in px, then you are specifying physical pixels and on a high-density device the same object will appear smaller.

Images are normally scaled based on the resource folder from which they are found. If you put a .png file in `/res/drawable`, the system assumes that it is correctly sized for mdpi—a display density of 160 pixels/inch. If the actual display happens to be 240 pixels/inch (hdpi), the system will automatically scale the image by a factor of 1.5 (= 240 / 160) when it loads it. The result is that the image will display at the same physical size on all screen densities.

You can use density-specific resource folders (`/res/drawable-mdpi`, `/res/drawable-hdpi`, etc.) to supply different graphics for different densities; this is commonly done when the system scaling reduces image quality unacceptably. You can also put graphics in `/res/drawable-nodpi` to suppress this scaling.

For more information, read the tutorial [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)